# Parquet Files Generation with hive

Tags: hive, hortonworks-data-platform, parquet, ambari, beeline

I'm trying to generate some parquet files with hive,to accomplish this i loaded a regular hive table from some .tbl files, throuh this command in hive:

CREATE TABLE REGION (
R_REGIONKEY BIGINT,
R_NAME STRING,
 R_COMMENT STRING)

ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
    STORED AS TEXTFILE
    location '/tmp/tpch-generate';

After this i just execute this 2 lines:

create table parquet_reion LIKE region STORED AS PARQUET;

insert into parquet_region select * from region;

But when i check the output generated in HDFS, i dont find any .parquet file, intead i find files names like 0000_0 to 0000_21, and the sum of their sizes are much bigger that the original tbl file.

What im i doing Wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Insert statement doesn't create file with extension but these are the parquet files.

You can use `DESCRIBE FORMATTED <table>` to show table information.

```
hive> DESCRIBE FORMATTED <table_name>
```

**Additional Note:** You can also create new table from source table using below query:

```
CREATE TABLE new_test row STORED AS PARQUET AS select * from source_table
```

It will create new table as parquet format and copies the structure as well as the data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But why are the sum of generated are bigger that the original file? shouldnt the parquet output be smaller? In my case the original tbl file is ~230MB, the generated files  0000_0 to 0000_21 have 98 mb each, much bigger.

Comment: It should not be bigger then original file. you might be inserting multiple time in same table. Can you please check with recreating the table  again. kindly drop it delete all old files and then recreate it.

Comment: i deleted the files and drop every table and even the database, and did it all again, but the result was the same

Comment: can you please post output of `ANALYZE TABLE tablename` ?